How to view upcoming events for multiple @Scheduled annotations?
Our java service has lots of scheduled tasks, that are defined using an @Scheduled annotation.
I'd like to take this list of Spring crons, and dump a list of them to a calendar format, so I can easily visualize when they'll run and overlap.
How can I take my list of crons, and see them in a calendar format?
I'm using Java 11, and have tried using this cron tool but it doesn't seem to recognize Spring crons.
Here's sample of the crons that I've tried to put into a crontab like format and tried in that crontool I mentioned, but many are invalid because I think they use a special cron format (ie Spring cron format doesn't match standard cron ?).
0 45 13 * * MON-FRI testCron1
0 15 13-18 * * MON-FRI testCron2
0 15 13-18 * * MON-FRI testCron3
0 0 13-18 * * MON-FRI testCron4
0 5,20,35,50 * * * * testCron5
0 */15 * * * MON-FRI testCron6
0 30 11-13 * * MON-FRI testCron7
0 10 4,16 * * * testCron8
0 0 4 * * * testCron9
0 0 8 * * * testCron10
0 0 0,6,12,18 * * * testCron11


The following shows how to get the next execution time as a LocalDateTime
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronExpression;


public static LocalDateTime getNextExecutionTime(Scheduled scheduledAnnotation, LocalDateTime startingLocalDateTime) throws Exception {
  String cronExpression = scheduledAnnotation.cron();
  CronExpression cron = CronExpression.parse(cronExpression);
  LocalDateTime result = cron.next(startingLocalDateTime);
  return result;
}

public static LocalDateTime getNextExecutionTime(Scheduled scheduledAnnotation) throws Exception {
  return getNextExecutionTime(scheduledAnnotation, LocalDateTime.now());
}

